# Error installing mail-stack-delivery

Tags: email, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, mail-server

So, I'm trying to set up an E-Mail server on an Ubuntu 10.04 VPS and when I try to use the command `sudo apt-get install mail-stack-delivery` (the package that I usually would use to get postfix and dovecot) it throws an error saying

> E: Couldn't find package mail-stack-delivery

I was wondering if anybody has had this issue before or sees something I'm doing blatantly wrong? I set up a test server earlier today using the exact same command and the package installed just fine.

EDIT: This is a fresh server, I have not done anything to it beyond whatever stock configuration is done by ChicagoVPS

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was that the file '/etc/apt/sources.list' didn't contain the universe repository.  To fix this, just edit it with VIM and add the repository.